# First value in implode returning different?

Tags: php, html

I am not sure why the first value in my array adds `<p>` tags, and the rest works well inside `li` tags.

```
//user posted variable
$checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];


//handling the form data and outputting it into a list
if(!empty($checks)){
$checkValues = array_values($checks);
$checkString = implode('<li style="list-style: none;">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_question', true).'', $checkValues);
}  


// I need this filter so it can parse the html in the email
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));


  //E-mailing my form data here
  $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $checkString, $headers);
```

This works, the email is sent, but for some reason it looks like this.

```
<p>1</p> //this is the first value it should look like below
<li style="list-style: none;">Suits1</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">Suits1</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">Suits1</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">Suits0</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">Suits0</li>
```

I wish I could ID the problem, but frankly I am not sure where the issue is? I feel its inside the `implode` maybe the HTML isnt written in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Implode` is adding the given String BETWEEN all occurences of the given Array. That means, that the Output you provided COULT NOT have been generated by the script you have given, because there is no `</li>` given anywhere.

Beside the fact, that nobody knows, what `get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_question', true)` will return, you are most likely looking to generate a List?

Then the code to go would be something like that:

NOTE: First Openig AND LAST closing tag Needs to be seperated, as implode will only add IN BETWEEN.
Therfore the "in between string" Needs to start with a closing tag, and end with a opening tag.

```
echo "<li>".implode("</li><li>", $myArray)."</li>";
```

Comment: Great, this really shed some perspective. I got it emailing the data in a nice tidy list, I had to write it like this `$checkString = '<li>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_question', true).''.implode('</li><li>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_question', true).'', $checkValues)."</li>";` adding the `post_meta` twice, just like the `<li>` your answer helped me understand that. Thanks @dognose